# Can I use a comma before "for" in this sentence

Tags: commas

Is there any reason why I can't use a comma before "for" in this sentence?

See Section 3.1, for further detail on MBI incidents.

My reason? Its easier to read with the comma when reading through the lengthy content where it lives.

I would often use this comma in user manuals, to refer to pages, but now I'm editing content for a government institution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FANBOYS** or **Coordinating Conjunctions** must be preceded by a comma. In your instance though, the word **for** is not a coordinating conjunction but rather a preposition.
Normally, commas do not precede prepositions.

*for further detail on MBI incidents*.

is a prepositional phrase which modifies the verb *see*, and it comes after the object Section 3.1. There should be no commas there.
The only reason for a comma to be in a sentence such as this is if the prepositional phrase was to be put before the subject of the sentence, as in:

For further detail on MBI incidents,* (you) See Section 3.1. - 
*you* being the subject

For further information on prepositional phrases you might use:
http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/prepphrases/

Comment: Hi Uhtred. Since we'd like to think we're providing expert answers on *English language and usage*, it's preferable that those answers conform to basic standards of punctuation - e.g. sentences start with a capitalised word. You can [edit] your post to fix this. :-)